# Minor issue with plot in base R - unwanted lines showing at top of plot

Tags: r, plot, border, radix

I have created a plot in base R, including 3 clipped 'ablines'. Despite using the "frame.plot = FALSE" function, which removes the box around the plot (see image example1), when I add my clipped ablines [using ablineclip] new framing lines appear above them (see image example2).

The code I am using is shown below:

```
library(plotrix)

op <- par(mar=c(5, 6, 4, 2) + 0.1)
plot(dif2$land_area ~ dif2$Year_no, ylim = c(1,4000), col.axis = rgb(68, 84, 106,max=255),xaxt='n', type='o', pch=16, col='red', font.axis=2, font.lab=2, col.lab=rgb( 113, 113, 113, max=255), xlab = 'Year', ylab = 'Total Land Area Changed to \nResidential Development (Ha)', frame.plot = FALSE, cex=1.3) 
rect(23.2,0,25.8,4000,col='grey',density = 8,border=T) 
rect(10.2,0,11.8,4000,col='grey',density = 8,border=T)
xlim(0,30)
axis(1,at= 1:30,labels=F)
axis(1,at= 1:30,tick=F, font.axis=2, col.axis = rgb(68, 84, 106, max=255),labels= c(1989:2018))
# the below section is that which seems to create the issue #
ablineclip(lm(land_area ~ Year_no, data = subset(dif2, int==0)), col='blue', lty=2, x1=1,x2=10, lwd=0.8)
ablineclip(lm(land_area ~ Year_no, data = subset(dif2, int==0)), col='blue', lty=2, x1=12,x2=23, lwd=0.8)
ablineclip(lm(land_area ~ Year_no, data = subset(dif2, int==1)), col='blue', lty=2, x1=26,x2=30, lwd=0.8)
```

Does anyone have any ideas of why the ablineclip function appears to be altering the borders of the plot?

[image: example1 - before addition of ablineclip function]
[image: example 2 - after addition of ablineclip function]

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set the y limits to the area clipped by `ablineclip` using the parameters `y1` and `y2`, ensuring that `y2` is below the top of your plot.

```r
ablineclip(lm(land_area ~ Year_no, data = subset(dif2, int==0)), 
           col = 'blue', lty = 2, x1 = 1, x2 = 10, y1 = 1, y2 = 3500, lwd = 0.8)

ablineclip(lm(land_area ~ Year_no, data = subset(dif2, int==0)), 
           col = 'blue', lty = 2, x1 = 12, x2 = 23, y1 = 1, y2 = 3500, lwd = 0.8)

ablineclip(lm(land_area ~ Year_no, data = subset(dif2, int==1)), 
           col = 'blue', lty = 2, x1 = 26, x2 = 30, y1 = 1, y2 = 3500,  lwd = 0.8)
```

Result:
[image]

Of course, I didn't have your data to work with so I had to make up a set that was similar (that's why the graph's shape is different to yours). The data I used was:

```r
dif2 <- structure(list(Year_no = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 
28), land_area = c(3165, 3179, 3076, 2772, 2816, 2605, 2565, 
2525, 2446, 2361, NA, 1966, 1911, 1790, 1819, 1710, 1673, 1555, 
1434, 1220, 1174, 1021, 1564, NA, NA, 2479, 2539, 2872), int = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -28L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks - the above was the more simple of the two solutions. Worked a treat!

Comment: @j_rah14 That's good to know. If this solved the problem for you, please consider accepting the answer so that other with the same issue can find their way to it too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's something in the code, see below, when you provide x1 and x2, it draws a line on the y limits + 1 :

```
> ablineclip
function (a = NULL, b = NULL, h = NULL, v = NULL, reg = NULL, 
    coef = NULL, untf = FALSE, x1 = NULL, x2 = NULL, y1 = NULL, 
    y2 = NULL, ...) 
{
    if (!is.null(c(x1, x2, y1, y2))) {
        oldclip <- par("usr")
        if (is.null(x1)) 
            x1 <- oldclip[1]
        if (is.null(x2)) 
            x2 <- oldclip[2]
        if (is.null(y1)) 
            y1 <- oldclip[3]
        if (is.null(y2)) 
            y2 <- oldclip[4]
        clip(x1, x2, y1, y2)
        abline(h = oldclip[4] + 1)
```

You can hack the code and comment out this line, or just use abline with a combination of predict. First we simulate something like your data:

```
set.seed(123)
dif2 = data.frame(land_area= rnbinom(30,mu=1500,size=5),
Year_no = seq_along(1989:2018))
dif2$int = rep(0:1,c(23,7))
dif2$int[23:27] = 1
dif2[1989:2018 %in% c(1999,2012,2013),c("land_area","int")] = NA
```

And plot:

```
library(plotrix)
op <- par(mar=c(5, 6, 4, 2) + 0.1)
plot(dif2$Year_no, dif2$land_area,ylim = c(1,4000), col.axis = rgb(68, 84, 106,max=255),xaxt='n', type='o', pch=16, col='red', font.axis=2, font.lab=2, col.lab=rgb( 113, 113, 113, max=255), xlab = 'Year', ylab = 'Total Land Area Changed to \nResidential Development (Ha)', frame.plot = FALSE, cex=1.3) 
rect(23.2,0,25.8,4000,col='grey',density = 8,border=T) 
rect(10.2,0,11.8,4000,col='grey',density = 8,border=T)
axis(1,at= 1:30,labels=F)
axis(1,at= 1:30,tick=F, font.axis=2, col.axis = rgb(68, 84, 106, max=255),labels= c(1989:2018))
```

We make the two fits, and you use predict to get the y values

```
fit1=lm(land_area ~ Year_no, data = subset(dif2, int==0))
fit2=lm(land_area ~ Year_no, data = subset(dif2, int==1))
lines(1:10,predict(fit1,data.frame(Year_no=1:10)),lty=8,col="blue")
lines(12:23,predict(fit1,data.frame(Year_no=12:23)),lty=8,col="blue")
lines(26:30,predict(fit2,data.frame(Year_no=26:30)),lty=8,col="blue")
```

[image]